# Need working cost count system for 5 items in code, and code not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver

> using System;
>
> class Program {
> public static void Main (string[] args) {
> string name;
> string Whiteout;
> string Vase;
> string Headphones;
> string Rubberduck;
> string Lightbulb;
>
> Console.WriteLine("Hello, welcome to Range Realm. What is your name?");
> name = Console.ReadLine();
>
> Console.WriteLine("Okay " + name + ", what would you like to buy today?");
> Console.ReadLine();
>
> Console.WriteLine("Oh. Sorry. The menu isn't available right now. Do you want to take a look around, see what you want? There is a list of five items. You must choose the amount of each item.");
>
> Console.WriteLine("The choices are: white out, vase, headphones, rubber duck, light bulb");
> Console.WriteLine("How many bottles of white out do you want?");
> Console.ReadLine();
>
> Console.WriteLine("WHITEOUT x" + );
> Console.WriteLine("How many Vases do you want?");
> Console.ReadLine();
>
> Console.WriteLine("VASE x" + );
> Console.WriteLine("How many pairs of headphones do you want?");
> Console.ReadLine();
>
> Console.WriteLine("HEADPHONES x" + );
> Console.WriteLine("How many Rubberducks do you want?");
> Console.ReadLine();
>
> Console.WriteLine("RUBBERDUCKS x" + );
> Console.WriteLine("How many Rubberducks do you want?");
> Console.ReadLine();
>
> Console.WriteLine("How many Light bulbs do you want?");
> Console.ReadLine();
> Console.WriteLine("LIGHTBULBS x" + );
> }
> }